# How to apply margin-top to card element but not to the entire container-fluid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make this container have a different background picture, but doing margin top to the card element moves everything along the picture. Here's my code using Bootstrap4:

```css
#card.container-fluid {
  background-image: url("../images/picture2.jpg");
  background-position: 12em;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-billboard">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div>
          <a>link</a>
          <a>lnk</a>
          <a>link</a>
          <a>link</a>
          <a>link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" id="card">
  <div class="card" style="width: 50%">
    <div class="card-body" id="bod">
      <h4 class="card-title">title</h4>
      <p class="card-text" style="text-align: justify;">
        text text tex
      </p>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img-bottom" src="image1.jpg" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried applying margin-top to .card, to #bod.card, but keeps moving the image as well, thank you in advance!

Comment: So you are trying to move the card-body down but the img to stay on the same spot? Its not really clear what you are asking for. Could you supply an example of the desired result?

Comment: I'm trying to move the entire card, but not the container's background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more solutions, you can use for example padding.

```
#card.container-fluid {padding-top: 20px;}
```

Comment: Thank you! Fixed my problem :)